# In the AWS S3 CLI, what happens if a move is interrupted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I call `aws s3 mv s3://myBucket/file s3://otherBucket/` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> before it's complete. What guarantees do I have about the state of my file afterward? I didn't see anything in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it wasn't a multi-part upload then the file simply won't exist on S3 since the upload didn't complete. If it was a multi-part upload, then some of the parts might have made it to S3. The file won't be visible since the upload didn't complete, but if you want to free up the space being used by the parts that did complete you can [define a lifecycle rule](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-lifecycle-management-update-support-for-multipart-uploads-and-delete-markers/) to clean those up.

Comment: Also, with just the right (wrong) timing, you would end up with 2 copies of the object, since S3 itself has no move or rename operation -- only copy followed by delete.  Interrupt after the copy but before the delete and you have both.  An edge case, to be sure, but possible.